# How to transpose panel data into correct form using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose, panel-data

I seem to be struggling with this conceptually so can't think how I will code it.

My data frame currently looks like this where I have split the GMT column into day, month and year columns and ID# is the ID number for each home with values underneath being the KwH usage at each time:

```
0    GMT         ID1    ID2   ID3   ...   ID1000   Day   Month   Year
1    01/01/2012  0.2    0.15  0.1   ...   0.1      1     1       2012
2    02/01/2012  0.3    0.2   0.2   ...   0.4      2     1       2012
3    03/01/2012  0.1    0.4   0.1   ...   0.5      3     1       2012
.    .           .      .     .     ...   .        .     .       . 
.    .           .      .     .     ...   .        .     .       . 
.    .           .      .     .     ...   .        .     .       .
1000 31/12/2012  0.3    0.2   0.05  ...   0.4      31    12      2012
```

However I want to transform it in such a way that it represents a panel data set such that it looks like:

```
0     ID   GMT         Day   Month   Year    KwH
1     1    01/01/2012  1     1       2012    0.2
2     1    02/01/2012  2     1       2012    0.3
3     1    03/01/2012  3     1       2012    0.1
.     .     .          .     .       .       .        
.     .     .          .     .       .       .        
.     .     .          .     .       .       .       
10000 1000 31/12/2012  31    12      2012    0.3
```

So essentially I want to transpose the dataframe in a way that transposes the ID columns so they become rows and the data associated with each ID becoming grouped by GMT ensuring the data is still matched correctly to the date columns.

I am struggling so far as the `df.transpose()` function appears to be too blunt an instrument to tarnspose with the nuance I am looking for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken a sample dataframe with GMT as index. Also, you can get later the day, month and year

```
            ID1  ID2    ID3  ID1000
GMT             
01/01/2012  0.2  0.15   0.1   0.1
02/01/2012  0.3  0.20   0.2   0.4
03/01/2012  0.1  0.40   0.1   0.5
```

You can then use [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to combine `GMT` and `ID` as the index and `KwH` as the values

```
output_df = df.unstack().to_frame()
output_df
```

[image]

Finally, you can make the required changes to get the df in the right format

```
output_df = output_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'ID', 0: 'KwH'})
output_df['ID'] = output_df['ID'].str.replace('ID', '') # remove ID from the ID column values
output_df['GMT'] = pd.to_datetime(output_df['GMT'])
output_df['Day'] = output_df['GMT'].dt.day
output_df['Month'] = output_df['GMT'].dt.month
output_df['Year'] = output_df['GMT'].dt.year
output_df
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! @Luca !  As it worked for your problem you may consider accepting, upvoting the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is for a subset of your data; you should be able to adapt it for the rest of your data:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'0': [1, 2, 3],
 'GMT': ['01/01/2012', '02/01/2012', '03/01/2012'],
 'ID1': [0.2, 0.3, 0.1],
 'ID2': [0.15, 0.2, 0.4],
 'ID3': [0.1, 0.2, 0.1],
 'ID1000': [0.1, 0.4, 0.5],
 'Day': [1, 2, 3],
 'Month': [1, 1, 1],
 'Year': [2012, 2012, 2012]})
```

[rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns, changing `ID` columns to `KwH`:

```
 reshape = df.rename(
    columns=lambda col: col.replace("ID", "KwH") if "ID" in col else col
)
reshape.columns
Index(['0', 'GMT', 'KwH1', 'KwH2', 'KwH3', 'KwH1000', 'Day', 'Month',
       'Year'],
      dtype='object')
```

Next apply [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to extract the data:

```
pd.wide_to_long(reshape, stubnames="KwH", i=["0", "GMT"], j="IDs", sep="")

                    Year    Month   Day KwH
0   GMT        IDs              
1   01/01/2012  1   2012    1   1   0.20
                2   2012    1   1   0.15
                3   2012    1   1   0.10
               1000 2012    1   1   0.10
2   02/01/2012  1   2012    1   2   0.30
                2   2012    1   2   0.20
                3   2012    1   2   0.20
              1000  2012    1   2   0.40
3   03/01/2012  1   2012    1   3   0.10
                2   2012    1   3   0.40
                3   2012    1   3   0.10
              1000  2012    1   3   0.50
```

Comment: Appreciate the help sammywemmy